# php artisan tinker laravel PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save() admin user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

First I have created an admin user using tinker then I deleted my migration in laravel5.1 then I did migration but this is the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::save() in /var/www/myblog/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/ExecutionLoop/Loop.php(76) : eval()'d code on line 1
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You created a default object from an empty value, which PHP is warning you about. So PHP created an object and assigned a value to a property. For the most part you got this:

```
$user = new stdClass;
$user->name = 'admin2';
```

In short you don't have an instance of a model, you have a stdClass object. This would give you a User model object:

```
$user = new App\User;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer the id property from the admin user table.
```

You should test it that way.

```
Schema::create('adminuser', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id'); // this line
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Created an object of model class and assign all values that want to be stored in table.

```
>>> $User=new App\User; //create a object
=> App\User {#3026}

>>> $User->name="Avi";
=> "Avi"

>>> $User->created_at="2020-01-01";
=> "2020-01-01"

>>> $User->age="20";
=> "20"

>>> $User->body="this is an information";
=> "this is an information"

>>> $User->save();
=> true
>>>
```

Assigment values to the columns that can be changed as per your table columns.

Answer (score 0):

`use  App\Models\User;` // call the namespace

`$user = new User;` //create a object

`$user->name = 'value';`

`$user->save();`

**You can code by looking at this example**